# Something I do not understand in the *.ld file

Tags: gcc, arm, gnu, ld

There are some statements in a *.ld file with  ARM GCC that I can not understand.

```
.init :
{
__initcall_start = .;
    KEEP(*(.initcall1.init))
    KEEP(*(.initcall2.init))
    KEEP(*(.initcall3.init))
    KEEP(*(.initcall4.init))
    KEEP(*(.initcall5.init))
    KEEP(*(.initcall6.init))
__initcall_end = .;
} >FLASH
```

I have searched the whole project with notepad, and the value `initcall1` only appeared in this *.ld file.

```
 E:\pos-orig\Gemini\system\sys_generic.ld (1 hit)
    Line 26:         KEEP(*(.initcall1.init))
```

What the `initcall1`,`initcall2`... used for?

And how can I understand the `KEEP(*(.initcall3.init))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [linker script](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.10/ld_3.html) says
that the sections named `.initcall1.init`,...,`.initcall6.init` from
all input files are to be output between the symbols `__initcall_start`
and `__initcall_end` in the output `.init` section and that all of them
are to be preserved from garbage collection.

> What the initcall1,initcall2... used for?

[Documentation: Kernel Initialization Mechanisms](https://lwn.net/Articles/141730/)

> how can i understand the 'KEEP(*(.initcall3.init))'?

[3.6.4.4 Input Section and Garbage Collection](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Input-Section-Keep.html#Input-Section-Keep)

Comment: I think you missed one key point.  The **input** section `initcallX.init` are ordered so that anything put in *initcall1.init* will come before *initcall2.init*, etc.  So the thing is a big array which has a pseudo-order.  Assembler and/or other code will iterate through the output section.  Otherwise, a fine answer.  Probably the code/idea was stolen from Linux and the OPs POS project doesn't use all the features.